# Consume Swagger API with multiple date-time formats

Tags: java, swagger

I am consuming an API that is outside of my control with a Swagger contract using the Swagger codegen CLI Jar version 2.3.1 and using the `java8` date library option, language is also Java.

In the API there are a few datetime fields all defined as :

```
"type": "string",
"format": "date-time"
```

Most of the values include the timezone, however one in particular does not. So we get both of these formats in fields that are defined in the same way:

```
"1963-08-15T23:59:59+02:00"
"1963-08-15T23:59:59"
```

This causes problems with the deserialzer as it never knows what format to handle.

I am using `OffsetDateTime` in the generated DTO classes as `LocalDateTime` just doesn't work - the generated code doesn't include a Gson adapter for it (See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6992).

I have tried setting a formatter for the deserializer with different formats, but it doesn't work, mostly because the second format above excludes the zone information:

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[xxx]");
apiClient.setOffsetDateTimeFormat(dtf);
```

I'm hoping to not edit the generated code too much as I would like to be able to regenerate in the future and I can't change the values being returned by the API as it's external.

Is there a way to tell the generated client to deserialize the different formats into `OffsetDateTime`, or perhaps default the time zone to something specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around this problem by editing the generated `JSON.java` file and changing the `OffsetDateTimeTypeAdapter` class to use a `ZonedDateTime` in the conversion in the `read` methofd:

```
return ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Then I've added the `JSON.java` file to the `.swagger-codegen-ignore` file. I doubt that file will change often.